# Ruby method interception

Tags: ruby, introspection

I want to intercept method calls on a ruby-class and being able to do something before and after the actual execution of the method. I tried the following code, but get the error:

> MethodInterception.rb:16:in `before_filter': (eval):2:in`alias_method': undefined method
>   `say_hello' for class`HomeWork'
>   (NameError)
>           from (eval):2:in `before_filter'

Can anybody help me to do it right?

```
class MethodInterception

  def self.before_filter(method)
    puts "before filter called"
    method = method.to_s
    eval_string = "
      alias_method :old_#{method}, :#{method}

      def #{method}(*args)
        puts 'going to call former method'
        old_#{method}(*args)
        puts 'former method called'
      end
    "
    puts "going to call #{eval_string}"
    eval(eval_string)
    puts "return"
  end
end

class HomeWork < MethodInterception
  before_filter(:say_hello)

  def say_hello
    puts "say hello"
  end

end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Less code was changed from original. I modified only 2 line.

```
class MethodInterception

  def self.before_filter(method)
    puts "before filter called"
    method = method.to_s
    eval_string = "
      alias_method :old_#{method}, :#{method}

      def #{method}(*args)
        puts 'going to call former method'
        old_#{method}(*args)
        puts 'former method called'
      end
    "
    puts "going to call #{eval_string}"
    class_eval(eval_string) # <= modified
    puts "return"
  end
end

class HomeWork < MethodInterception

  def say_hello
    puts "say hello"
  end

  before_filter(:say_hello) # <= change the called order
end
```

This works well.

```
HomeWork.new.say_hello
#=> going to call former method
#=> say hello
#=> former method called
```

Answer (score 15):

I just came up with this:

```
module MethodInterception
  def method_added(meth)
    return unless (@intercepted_methods ||= []).include?(meth) && !@recursing

    @recursing = true # protect against infinite recursion

    old_meth = instance_method(meth)
    define_method(meth) do |*args, &block|
      puts 'before'
      old_meth.bind(self).call(*args, &block)
      puts 'after'
    end

    @recursing = nil
  end

  def before_filter(meth)
    (@intercepted_methods ||= []) << meth
  end
end
```

Use it like so:

```
class HomeWork
  extend MethodInterception

  before_filter(:say_hello)

  def say_hello
    puts "say hello"
  end
end
```

Works:

```
HomeWork.new.say_hello
# before
# say hello
# after
```

The basic problem in your code was that you renamed the method in your `before_filter` method, but then in your client code, you called `before_filter` before the method was actually defined, thus resulting in an attempt to rename a method which doesn't exist.

The solution is simple: Don't Do That™!

Well, okay, maybe not so simple. You *could* simply force your clients to always call `before_filter` *after* they have defined their methods. However, that is bad API design.

So, you have to somehow arrange for your code to defer the wrapping of the method until it actually exists. And that's what I did: instead of redefining the method inside the `before_filter` method, I only record the fact that it is to be redefined later. Then, I do the *actual* redefining in the `method_added` hook.

There is a tiny problem in this, because if you add a method inside of `method_added`, then of course it will immediately get called again and add the method again, which will lead to it being called again, and so on. So, I need to guard against recursion.

Note that this solution actually *also* enforces an ordering on the client: while the OP's version *only* works if you call `before_filter` *after* defining the method, my version only works if you call it *before*. However, it is trivially easy to extend so that it doen't suffer from that problem.

Note also that I made some additional changes that are unrelated to the problem, but that I think are more Rubyish:

- use a mixin instead of a class: inheritance is a very valuable resource in Ruby, because you can only inherit from one class. Mixins, however, are cheap: you can mix in as many as you want. Besides: can you really say that Homework IS-A MethodInterception?
- use `Module#define_method` instead of `eval`: `eval` is evil. 'Nuff said. (There was absolutely no reason whatsoever to use `eval` in the first place, in the OP's code.)
- use the method wrapping technique instead of `alias_method`: the `alias_method` chain technique pollutes the namespace with useless `old_foo` and `old_bar` methods. I like my namespaces clean.

---

I just fixed some of the limitations I mentioned above, and added a few more features, but am too lazy to rewrite my explanations, so I repost the modified version here:

```
module MethodInterception
  def before_filter(*meths)
    return @wrap_next_method = true if meths.empty?
    meths.delete_if {|meth| wrap(meth) if method_defined?(meth) }
    @intercepted_methods += meths
  end

  private

  def wrap(meth)
    old_meth = instance_method(meth)
    define_method(meth) do |*args, &block|
      puts 'before'
      old_meth.bind(self).(*args, &block)
      puts 'after'
    end
  end

  def method_added(meth)
    return super unless @intercepted_methods.include?(meth) || @wrap_next_method
    return super if @recursing == meth

    @recursing = meth # protect against infinite recursion
    wrap(meth)
    @recursing = nil
    @wrap_next_method = false

    super
  end

  def self.extended(klass)
    klass.instance_variable_set(:@intercepted_methods, [])
    klass.instance_variable_set(:@recursing, false)
    klass.instance_variable_set(:@wrap_next_method, false)
  end
end

class HomeWork
  extend MethodInterception

  def say_hello
    puts 'say hello'
  end

  before_filter(:say_hello, :say_goodbye)

  def say_goodbye
    puts 'say goodbye'
  end

  before_filter
  def say_ahh
    puts 'ahh'
  end
end

(h = HomeWork.new).say_hello
h.say_goodbye
h.say_ahh
```

Comment: One note: alias_method pollutes the namespace but using alias_method + send will result in faster execution than getting a reference to the method (about 50% faster in my test).

Answer (score 0):

Jörg W Mittag's solution is pretty nice. If you want something more robust (read well tested) the best resource would be the rails callbacks module.

Comment: did he say he was using rails??!

Comment: I count less than 50 lines of code in Jörg's example (Homework class included). Surely we can come up with a strategy to test it until we consider it robust and well-tested.

Comment: @banister: Don't know where Swanand got that crazy notion from. Only 98% of ruby folk use Rails.

Comment: Which part of Rails does the callbacks module reside in? ActiveSupport?

Comment: @banister: He never did! I directed him to Rails because it has a similar functionality which he can learn /copy from.
@Andrew: :-), that too.

Comment: @Corbin: Sure, we definitely can. But it isn't already, and Rails has, thats why the suggestion.